# How can be $\log(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ equal to $\log(\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, logarithms

In a book, $\log(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ is given as the solution of an differential equation. I by properly managing where minus sigh "-" occurs and using a different anti-derivative computing approach can obtain $\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2 - 1)$ that is equal to $\log(\sqrt{x^2-1})$. WolframAlpha also computes $\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2 - 1)$ result. Puzzled, I ordered WA to compute difference between the "$1-x^2$" and "$x^2 - 1$" versions of the logarithm. It is zero, and that value spans on whole $R$, which is also weird, as there is no real square root of $1-x^2$ for $x$ beyond $<-1, 1>$. What's happening here ? Is $\log(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ equal to $\log(\sqrt{x^2-1})$ on whole $R$?

Here is what I enter into WA to test the situation: ln( sqrt( x^2 -1 )) - ln( sqrt( 1 - x^2 )) + 1

Comment: Of course they aren't equal, being defined on different domains: $|x|<1$ the first, $|x|>1$ the second.

Comment: @egreg: that would mean the book is wrong (there is some chance for this) and that output of WA for following is also wrong:  ln( sqrt( x^2 -1 )) - ln( sqrt( 1 - x^2 )) + 1

Comment: As far as I can see, WA *doesn't* say they are equal, but that the difference has *zero real part*.

Comment: If the book says the solution is $\log\sqrt{1-x^2}$, you can see the solution is defined over $(-1,1)$; your solution is defined over $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, so you're solving a different problem.

Comment: They are equal up to a piecewise constant, which means they have the same derivative. i.e. they are both valid antiderivatives even though they are not equal.

Comment: @ChipHurst: entering "plot ln( sqrt( 1- x^2 ))" into WA and then separately "plot ln( sqrt( x^2 -1 ))" shows, that the logarithms are indeed equal (their real parts) if complex numbers are used, i.e. this probably means a definition of logarithm for complex numbers

Comment: @egreg my above answer ^

Comment: @VolkerAmnu Right. If you enter "plot log(sqrt(x^2-1)) - log(sqrt(1-x^2))" into WA, you can see that the real part is zero, but the imaginary part is a piecewise constant. i.e. log(sqrt(x^2-1)) = log(sqrt(1-x^2)) + c(x), where c(x) = pi i/2 if -1 < x < 1 and -pi i/2 otherwise. The derivative of c(x) is 0 (with removable singularities at ±1). So to answer your original question, log(sqrt(x^2-1)) is never equal to log(sqrt(1-x^2)), but both are valid antiderivates.

Comment: As was mentioned before, as these two are solutions to a certain integral, they are differing by a constant which is $log(i)$.